# How can I stream video from the camera to a <Image>

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

Im making an app that should let the user see video from the camera on the back of the phone in a small frame in my app (300x300)

But im having some problems fetching the stream. I've tried a CameraCaptureTask but does not work on my phone. I seems to open the video app and them close it, returning to the app, right away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the Basic Camera Sample from here: [Code Samples for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28v=VS.92%29.aspx#BKMK_CameraAndPhotos)

It's an excellent, fully featured example of probably everything you'll need for your project.

Here's the 'walkthrough' version if you're interested: [How to: Create a Base Camera Application for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202956%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)